# Nancyfx как возвратить картинку?

Tags: c#

В общем хочу просто возвратить на странице картинку. Чтобы появилась ссылка типа 
`xxx.ru/image.png`

Нашел сниппет на гитхабе, но не совсем понятно что оно делает https://gist.github.com/grumpydev/4605541

Comment: Эээ... А что такое nancyfx? Это какой-то web-фреймворк?

Comment: можно больше информации? `xxx.ru/image.png` вывести в респонс ссылку не проблема, а вот проблема понять что вы хотите :)

Comment: У меня в проекте в корне есть картинка image.png. При переходе по xxx.ru/image.png я хочу чтобы открывалась эта картинка.

Comment: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2118#issuecomment-157758074